# Best SIP VOIP hardware ever. Suggestions?

Tags: voip, sip, telephony

I need a VOIP adapter that has at least these characteristics:

- 1 ethernet port, so I can make SIP VOIP calls. The box must allow one or two SIP accounts;
- 1 FXS port, so I can connect it to my analogue telephone line and receive regular calls;
- 1 FXO port, so I can connect my analogue telephone to it;

So, the box should be able to make and receive calls from SIP and from the regular phone line using the same analogue telephone. The box should work by itself. No USB stuff that need the computer on.

I will be connecting this box with my ethernet router that is permanently ON. The router has QoS and DHCP server.

Please refrain from suggesting the following brands: **Asus**, **Linksys** and **Sippura** and also chinese and/or low quality stuff. I have bought VOIP boxes from all these brands and had to return it to the store, because they are all really bad (lost sync, hangs, lack of support, lack of firmware updates, lots of bugs, do not forward callerID to the phone, etc.);

I was looking from trustable brands as Cisco, Alcatel, etc. First grade stuff.

Two of the problems I had with all these boxes I had in the past was:

- the boxes do not pass the callerID information to the phone connected to it;
- they all lost sync to the SIP server, constantly, several times a day;
- they all show constantly hanging and needed restart.

I am in Portugal and I need the box to understand the callerID used here (ETSI DTMF during ring and/or ITU-T V2.3).

So, tell me what brands do you guy suggest and why do you recommend that brand/model in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AVM Fritz Box](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fritz!Box) fulfils most of your requirements. It is very popular in Germany but quality is closer to Linksys than Cicso.

Comment: it would be great if they had something that was not an ADSL modem, as I need this box to connect to a network that already have a modem. Another question: what kind of AC outlet plugs do you use in Germany? Is the same as in Portugal? (we here use this  http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bb/PC_flex_with_CEE_7-7_plug.png).

Comment: It's possible to turn off the modem with many models. Probably all except very old ones. Yes, plugs and voltage in Germany are the same as in Portugal.

Comment: I have an adapter here, a zoom x5v that is almost like this AVM. The problem is that it just sends the voip over ADSL and not over the local network... I am afraid this works like that. Thanks for the information about voltage and plugs in Germany!